# In a webapp GUI builder throws error message

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a very complex user interface constructed using the GUI builder.

All was working as promised until I added 8 more severside functions to the code.
In the GUI Builder (when I try to attach these new functions to mouse up, The GUI Builder announces "An Unexpected Error occured" in a pink stripe across the top of the script editor.

When I clear the error, the project appears to be OK and I can save and run the application.
If I go to any previously object that triggers a server side handler and attempt to change it I get the same error.

It is my suspicion that the failure happens when the GUI builder tries to load the list of available functions from the code source.  My code is running upwards of 50 Gscript functions.

If there are some limits on what the GUI Builder can handle it would be really nice to have those documented.  Also a more meaningful error message would be nice.

I assume that I can still add/attach these handlers in the code base (outside of GUI Builder)?

Comment: Try to identify where the error is occurring. Use `Logger.log` to see what script is being called, and then you may want read [this blog post](http://googleappsscript.blogspot.com/2010/06/debugging-event-handlers.html) about error handling. You don't necessarily need to email yourself the error message. You can just log it.

Comment: It is the GUI Builder (not script execution) that is the problem.  I do not know how to use logger.log for GUI Builder execution.

Answer (score 0):

This error message comes up when you try to `getElementById` using an Id that doesn't exist.  Please check all the widget Ids in your GUI.I'm pretty sure your issue is not related to some systemic limitation, I've made some complex UIs with the GUI builder without issue.

Comment: I have experienced the result of the error you mention when running the script, but in this instance it is the GUI builder itself throwing the error.  I can't understand how a bad getElenent in the gscript could cause the GUI Builder to choke up???

Comment: Mmmm I see, sorry I misunderstood your question. You could indeed create the handlers in the code itself, that anyway what I always do because I don't like so much the way it is implemented in the GUI builder.

Comment: Are you also sure that you use the exact name for the function that is called by the handler?  It's so easy to get small typos in that GUI interface...(this is also true for callbackElements, the place available is pretty small:-)

Comment: Yes -- I always select it from the dropdown of all availlable functions in the script.  The error occurs (in the Gui Buider because this list can no longer be displayed.  While in the script editor the Select functions list is OK (although there is no scroll bar to view the off screen functions!). testing with functions removed has not solved the proble, therefore my concern that there was a numeric limit in the GUI Builder is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

you d better use a full scripted apps instead of GUI..I gave up with GUI since there is some strange stuff..as ID managment, name managment, radio button (bug as well in normal scripting..^^)..GUI is a black box for me..just try to make your app with vertical horizontal  or xy panel...and you will be able to know who do wa and when... with the logger